# Will sending `kill -11` to java process raises a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, jvm-hotspot

For example, the HotSpot JVM implement null-pointer detection by catching SIGSEGV signal.  So if we manually generate a SIGSEGV from external, will that also be recognized as `NullPointerException` **in some circumstances** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will sending `kill -11` to java process raises a NullPointerException?

It should not: a `NullPointerException` is a specific exception that occurs when an application tries to use an object reference that has the null value.

Yet, from [JavaSE 17 / Troubleshooting guide / Handle Signals and Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/troubleshoot/handle-signals-and-exceptions.html#GUID-CBA7BA16-F89F-4BE2-B653-139BABA997D4)

> The Java HotSpot VM installs signal handlers to implement various features and to handle fatal error conditions.
>
> For example, in an optimization to avoid explicit null checks in cases where `java.lang.NullPointerException` will be thrown rarely, the `SIGSEGV` signal is caught and handled, and the `NullPointerException` is thrown.
>
> In general, there are two categories where signal/traps happen:
>
> - When signals are expected and handled, like implicit null-handling. Another example is the safepoint polling mechanism, which protects a page in memory when a safepoint is required. Any thread that accesses that page causes a `SIGSEGV`, which results in the execution of a stub that brings the thread to a safepoint.
> - Unexpected signals. That includes a `SIGSEGV` when executing in VM code, Java Native Interface (JNI) code, or native code. In these cases, the signal is unexpected, so fatal error handling is invoked to create the error log and terminate the process.

That approach allows the JVM to optimize performance by reducing the overhead of explicit null checks in the code, relying instead on the operating system's memory protection mechanisms to detect access to null references. When such access occurs, the operating system generates a `SIGSEGV` signal, which the JVM then interprets as an attempt to dereference a null pointer, leading to the throwing of a `NullPointerException`.

However, it is important to note that this is an *internal* mechanism of the JVM and is distinct from externally generated `SIGSEGV` signals, such as those sent using the `kill` command. External `SIGSEGV` signals are generally used to indicate serious errors, including invalid memory access, and are more likely to result in a JVM crash or core dump rather than a `NullPointerException`.

```bash
+---------------------+         +-----------------------------------+
| External Process    |         | Java Process running on HotSpot   |
| sending SIGSEGV     | ------> | JVM                               |
| (kill -11)          |         | Likely JVM Crash or Core Dump     |
+---------------------+         +-----------------------------------+
```

---

> Is the JVM always capable of detecting whether an external `SIGSEGV` is an external `SIGSEGV` or is it possible to confuse an external `SIGSEGV` for a null access when it happens at a specific time, i.e. when a potential null access is expected?

Again, it should not, but this is an *implementation*-specific aspect of JVM behavior.
That means the likelihood of such confusion happening in practice may vary depending on the JVM version, the specific code being executed, and the state of the JVM at the time of the signal.

See for instance "[How does the JVM know when to throw a NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36955888/6309)"

> The JVM could implement the null check using virtual memory hardware. The JVM arranges that page zero in its virtual address space is mapped to a page that is unreadable + unwriteable.
>
> Since null is represented as zero, when Java code tries to dereference null this will try to access a non-addressible page and will lead to the OS delivering a "segfault" signal to the JVM.
>
> The JVM's segfault signal handler could trap this, figure out where the code was executing, and create and throw an NPE on the stack of the appropriate thread.

In that scenario, it should be easy to distinguish a trapped signal from within the code execution, from a received signal from the OS.

Also: "[Can a `SIGSEGV` in Java not crash the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43346525/6309)"

> There are definitely scenarios where the JVM's `SIGSEGV` signal handler may turn the `SIGSEGV` event into a Java exception.
> You will only get a JVM hard crash if that cannot happen; e.g. if the thread that triggered the `SIGSEGV` was executing code in a native library when the event happened.

[For instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501096/avoid-nullpointerexception-on-jni-vm-startup#comment76037746_44501096):

> [HotSpot JVM deliberately generates SIGSEGV at startup](https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/68758c5ab0c1/src/cpu/x86/vm/vm_version_x86.cpp#l259) to check certain CPU features. There is no switch to turn it off. I suggest skipping `SIGSEGV` in `gdb` altogether, because JVM uses it for its own purpose in many cases.

---

> What if the stack happens to locate at accessing an address when the `SIGSEGV` is triggered externally?

The hotspot had a major refactoring around signal handling in [JDK-8255711](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8255711), resulting in [commit dd8e4ff](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/dd8e4ffbe559568222fc21c09d162a867df2e805).

The current code is [`os_linux_x86.cpp#PosixSignals::pd_hotspot_signal_handler`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/9902d2eb177072c108933056cba544cc5a34bb54/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/os_linux_x86.cpp#L207-L421)

```cpp
  // decide if this trap can be handled by a stub
  address stub = nullptr;

  address pc          = nullptr;

  //%note os_trap_1
  if (info != nullptr && uc != nullptr && thread != nullptr) {
    pc = (address) os::Posix::ucontext_get_pc(uc);

    if (sig == SIGSEGV && info->si_addr == 0 && info->si_code == SI_KERNEL) {
      // An irrecoverable SI_KERNEL SIGSEGV has occurred.
      // It's likely caused by dereferencing an address larger than TASK_SIZE.
      return false;
    }

    // Handle ALL stack overflow variations here
    if (sig == SIGSEGV) {
      address addr = (address) info->si_addr;

      // check if fault address is within thread stack
      if (thread->is_in_full_stack(addr)) {
        // stack overflow
        if (os::Posix::handle_stack_overflow(thread, addr, pc, uc, &stub)) {
          return true; // continue
        }
      }
    }

    if ((sig == SIGSEGV) && VM_Version::is_cpuinfo_segv_addr(pc)) {
      // Verify that OS save/restore AVX registers.
      stub = VM_Version::cpuinfo_cont_addr();
    }

    if (thread->thread_state() == _thread_in_Java) {
      // Java thread running in Java code => find exception handler if any
      // a fault inside compiled code, the interpreter, or a stub

      if (sig == SIGSEGV && SafepointMechanism::is_poll_address((address)info->si_addr)) {
        stub = SharedRuntime::get_poll_stub(pc);
      } else if (sig == SIGBUS /* && info->si_code == BUS_OBJERR */) {
        // BugId 4454115: A read from a MappedByteBuffer can fault
        // here if the underlying file has been truncated.
        // Do not crash the VM in such a case.
        CodeBlob* cb = CodeCache::find_blob(pc);
        CompiledMethod* nm = (cb != nullptr) ? cb->as_compiled_method_or_null() : nullptr;
        bool is_unsafe_arraycopy = thread->doing_unsafe_access() && UnsafeCopyMemory::contains_pc(pc);
        if ((nm != nullptr && nm->has_unsafe_access()) || is_unsafe_arraycopy) {
          address next_pc = Assembler::locate_next_instruction(pc);
          if (is_unsafe_arraycopy) {
            next_pc = UnsafeCopyMemory::page_error_continue_pc(pc);
          }
          stub = SharedRuntime::handle_unsafe_access(thread, next_pc);
        }
      }
      else

#ifdef AMD64
      if (sig == SIGFPE  &&
          (info->si_code == FPE_INTDIV || info->si_code == FPE_FLTDIV)) {
        stub =
          SharedRuntime::
          continuation_for_implicit_exception(thread,
                                              pc,
                                              SharedRuntime::
                                              IMPLICIT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO);
#else
      if (sig == SIGFPE /* && info->si_code == FPE_INTDIV */) {
        // HACK: si_code does not work on linux 2.2.12-20!!!
        int op = pc[0];
        if (op == 0xDB) {
          // FIST
          // TODO: The encoding of D2I in x86_32.ad can cause an exception
          // prior to the fist instruction if there was an invalid operation
          // pending. We want to dismiss that exception. From the win_32
          // side it also seems that if it really was the fist causing
          // the exception that we do the d2i by hand with different
          // rounding. Seems kind of weird.
          // NOTE: that we take the exception at the NEXT floating point instruction.
          assert(pc[0] == 0xDB, "not a FIST opcode");
          assert(pc[1] == 0x14, "not a FIST opcode");
          assert(pc[2] == 0x24, "not a FIST opcode");
          return true;
        } else if (op == 0xF7) {
          // IDIV
          stub = SharedRuntime::continuation_for_implicit_exception(thread, pc, SharedRuntime::IMPLICIT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO);
        } else {
          // TODO: handle more cases if we are using other x86 instructions
          //   that can generate SIGFPE signal on linux.
          tty->print_cr("unknown opcode 0x%X with SIGFPE.", op);
          fatal("please update this code.");
        }
#endif // AMD64
      } else if (sig == SIGSEGV &&
                 MacroAssembler::uses_implicit_null_check(info->si_addr)) {
          // Determination of interpreter/vtable stub/compiled code null exception
          stub = SharedRuntime::continuation_for_implicit_exception(thread, pc, SharedRuntime::IMPLICIT_NULL);
      }
    } else if ((thread->thread_state() == _thread_in_vm ||
                thread->thread_state() == _thread_in_native) &&
               (sig == SIGBUS && /* info->si_code == BUS_OBJERR && */
               thread->doing_unsafe_access())) {
        address next_pc = Assembler::locate_next_instruction(pc);
        if (UnsafeCopyMemory::contains_pc(pc)) {
          next_pc = UnsafeCopyMemory::page_error_continue_pc(pc);
        }
        stub = SharedRuntime::handle_unsafe_access(thread, next_pc);
    }

    // jni_fast_Get<Primitive>Field can trap at certain pc's if a GC kicks in
    // and the heap gets shrunk before the field access.
    if ((sig == SIGSEGV) || (sig == SIGBUS)) {
      address addr = JNI_FastGetField::find_slowcase_pc(pc);
      if (addr != (address)-1) {
        stub = addr;
      }
    }
  }
```

The JVM uses various checks to determine the context of a `SIGSEGV` signal. However, I do not see a straightforward mechanism to distinguish an externally sent `SIGSEGV` from one internally generated due to a null reference access.

The signal handler examines the execution context, including the program counter and the stack, to infer the cause of the `SIGSEGV`. In case of a null reference, it looks for specific patterns that suggest a null pointer exception. But if an external `SIGSEGV` happens to coincide precisely with a situation where the JVM's execution state resembles that of a null pointer access, distinguishing between the two can be challenging.

However, such a scenario is relatively unlikely due to the level of precision required in timing.

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question, which was, is the JVM always capable of detecting whether an external `SIGSEGV` is an external `SIGSEGV` or is it possible to confuse an external `SIGSEGV` for a `null` access when it happens at a specific time, i.e. when a potential `null` access is expected.

Comment: @Holger I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: @Holger  can JVM  always detect that correctly? Because the external signal can happen at any time, including the moment at which JVM thought itself to be in Nullpointer status

Comment: @choxsword Yes, but it happens through different execution paths (each with their own execution stack). The JVM should be able to differentiate from *where* the SIGSEV is coming from.

Comment: @choxsword I know, that’s the question and if I knew the answer for sure, I would post an answer.  I suppose, the operating system must be able to tell the JVM which thread triggered the signal and since external signals lack an associated thread, they must be distinguishable.

Comment: @VonC but it seems that linux does not tell user where the signal is come from.

Comment: @choxsword The internal execution stack should still be able to illustrate whether the SIGSEV is trapped from a NPE, or from an external signal.

Comment: what if the stack happens to locate at accessing an address when the SIGSEGV is triggered externally?

Comment: @choxsword I have edited the answer to include the actual code from the Hotspot which handles signals for Linux. I really don't think such a scenario is likely.

Answer (score 12):

##### Summary

Yes, in some marginal cases an external `kill` command may cause a bogus `NullPointerException` in a Java application. This behavior is platform-dependent and difficult to reproduce, however, I managed to trigger this in practice.

##### Background

HotSpot JVM employs a technique called ["implicit null check"](https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/25-implicit-null-checks/), where the JVM compiles an access to an object field which offset is less than a page size (4096) to a single load/store instruction without extra overhead for checking the object reference for `null`. If such an instruction is executed for `null` reference, the OS raises `SIGSEGV`. The JVM's signal handler catches this signal and transfers control to the code that throws `NullPointerException`.

Not every `SIGSEGV` ends up with a NPE. [HotSpot signal handler](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/e47cf611c9490225e50a548787cbba66ab147058/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/os_linux_x86.cpp#L207) checks that

- the current thread is a Java thread;
- SIGSEGV occurs in a JIT-compiled code;
- the address being accessed is within zero page (0x0 - 0xfff);
- the fault instruction is marked as "implicit exception" and there is an exception handler assigned to this instruction.

In theory, if we craft a signal that satisfies all the conditions, HotSpot will treat it as NPE.

##### Practice

To increase chances of a user signal hitting the right instruction, we'll write an infinite loop that repeatedly stores to an object field. To prevent hoisting of the null check, the reference itself should be loaded from a volatile field.

```
public class BogusNPE {
    static volatile BogusNPE X = new BogusNPE();

    int n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            BogusNPE x0 = X, x1 = X, x2 = X, x3 = X, x4 = X, x5 = X, x6 = X, x7 = X, x8 = X, x9 = X;
            x0.n = x1.n = x2.n = x3.n = x4.n = x5.n = x6.n = x7.n = x8.n = x9.n = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I generated 10 stores in a row, all with an implicit null check.

Use `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly` to verify that the corresponding `mov` instructions are annotated with `implicit exception`:

```
  0x00007fb4a4bd440c:   mov    0x70(%r10),%edx              ;*getstatic X {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                            ; - BogusNPE::main@32 (line 8)
  0x00007fb4a4bd4410:   mov    0x70(%r10),%ebp              ;*getstatic X {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                            ; - BogusNPE::main@37 (line 8)
  0x00007fb4a4bd4414:   mov    0x70(%r10),%eax              ;*getstatic X {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                            ; - BogusNPE::main@42 (line 8)
  0x00007fb4a4bd4418:   mov    %r12d,0xc(%r12,%rax,8)       ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007fb4a4bd4456
                                                            ;*putfield n {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                            ; - BogusNPE::main@66 (line 9)
  0x00007fb4a4bd441d:   mov    %r12d,0xc(%r12,%rbp,8)       ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007fb4a4bd4468
                                                            ;*putfield n {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                            ; - BogusNPE::main@70 (line 9)
  0x00007fb4a4bd4422:   mov    %r12d,0xc(%r12,%rdx,8)       ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007fb4a4bd447c
                                                            ;*putfield n {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                            ; - BogusNPE::main@74 (line 9)
```

Run the program and get its PID:

```
$ jps
256 BogusNPE
280 Jps
```

Here pid=256, but we should send the signal not to a process, but to the particular thread. ID of the main thread is usually pid+1, that is 257.

```
$ sudo kill -11 257
```

It may take several attempts before we finally achieve the goal:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot assign field "n" because "x5" is null
        at BogusNPE.main(BogusNPE.java:9)
```

##### Nuances

On x86 platform, I could trigger NPE without `sudo`, but on 64-bit platforms `sudo` is important. Also, it's substantial that PID of the shell where we run `kill` is less than 4096. And that is why.

HotSpot [checks](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/e47cf611c9490225e50a548787cbba66ab147058/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/os_linux_x86.cpp#L311C9-L312) that the fault address `siginfo->si_addr` is located in zero page (otherwise load/store instruction requires an explicit null check). However, `si_addr` is set only when SIGSEGV is raised by kernel, we cannot control it with `kill` command. For user-generated signals, `si_pid` (sending process ID) and `si_uid` (user ID of sending process) are set instead.

By a lucky chance, `siginfo_t` structure [contains a union](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/types/siginfo_t.h#L36-L124), where `si_addr` overlaps with `si_pid` and `si_uid`.

```
63       31       0
+-----------------+
|     si_addr     |
+-----------------+
| si_uid | si_pid |
+-----------------+
```

So, to produce `si_addr` value between 0 and 4096, we need to make `si_uid = 0` (that is, invoke kill by user 0 or `root`), and set `si_pid < 4096`. On 32-bit systems, `si_addr` overlaps with `si_pid` only.

If the signal misses `mov` instruction with an implicit null check, or if `si_addr` is larger than the page size, the JVM will crash with a fatal error instead of throwing NPE.

##### Can JVM detect the source of SIGSEGV?

It is certainly possible to distinguish user-generated SIGSEGV from a signal caused by invalid memory access. The signal handler could just check `si_code` field of [siginfo_t](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) structure:

- for a real NullPointerException, `si_code` will be `SEGV_MAPERR`;
- for a signal sent by `kill`, `tgkill` or `sigqueue`, the code will be `SI_USER`, `SI_TKILL` or `SI_QUEUE` respectively.

However, current HotSpot implementation does not do that, and therefore it is possible to fool the JVM using the above trick.

Comment: Got the `NullPointerException` on the 3rd attempt, +1

Comment: you never seize to amaze with your knowledge and perseverance. +1

Comment: Great answer (more accurate [than mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77501115/6309)). I have returned to you the bounty you should have had.

Answer (score -1):

Sending a `kill -11` to a Java process will send a `SIGSEGV` (segmentation fault) signal to that process. `SIGSEGV` is a signal sent by the operating system to a process when it makes an invalid memory reference, or segmentation fault.

In the context of the Java HotSpot JVM, a `NullPointerException` is typically raised internally by the JVM when it detects an attempt to dereference a null reference. This is often implemented by catching a `SIGSEGV` signal that results from such an attempt. The JVM has a mechanism to differentiate between a `SIGSEGV` that is a legitimate `NullPointerException` and other segmentation faults.

When you externally send a `SIGSEGV` to a Java process (using `kill -11`), it's not equivalent to the JVM internally detecting a null reference access. Instead, it's an abrupt signal to the process that it has attempted to access memory that it shouldn't, which is typically outside the scope of normal Java exception handling.

To answer your questions:

1. **Will sending `kill -11` to a Java process raise a `NullPointerException`?**: No, sending a `kill -11` (or `SIGSEGV`) to a Java process will not raise a `NullPointerException`. Instead, it will likely cause the JVM to crash or terminate unexpectedly because it's a signal that the process has attempted to access an invalid memory location.
2. **Is the JVM capable of detecting whether a `SIGSEGV` is external or due to a null access?**: Yes, the JVM is generally capable of distinguishing between a `SIGSEGV` caused by a genuine null pointer dereference within the Java program (which would result in a `NullPointerException`) and other causes of `SIGSEGV`, such as an external `kill` command or other invalid memory accesses. The JVM uses its internal mechanisms to determine the context of the SIGSEGV and whether it corresponds to a null reference access.
3. **Can an external SIGSEGV be confused for a null access?**: Under normal circumstances, an external `SIGSEGV` should not be confused with a null access within the JVM. The JVM's signal handlers are designed to interpret the context of the fault and distinguish between different causes of `SIGSEGV`. However, in complex systems or in cases of JVM bugs, unexpected behavior can occur, but this would be highly unusual and not the norm.